# Passing matrix element as function handle

Tags: matlab, function-handle, state-space

I have applied inverse laplace transform to a matrix and now it is a function of `t`. My goal is to substitute `t` value and get the result matrix. I intended this code to be pretty straight foward but I'm not getting it work. This is what I tried:

```
clc,clear all, close all

% Parameters
syms s
r=3.33;
l = 4.56*10^-3;
j = 4.96*10^-5;
b = 4.59*10^-5;
k = 0.0332;

% State Matrices
F = [-r/l -k/l 0; k/j -b/j 0; 0 1 0]
G = [1/l; 0; 0]


sI = s*eye(3,3)
aux_A = (adjoint(sI-F))/det(sI-F)
laplaceA = ilaplace(aux_A)

result_matrix = @(t) laplaceA

%Assuming t = 0.01
result_matrix(0.01)
```

Assuming that my goal is just substitute `t` values within `laplaceA` matrix, I am open to any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Replacing `syms` Variables in Symbolic Functions

Using `subs()` to substitute the `Input` parameter of the anonymous function/function handle may be as way to replace all the `t` terms in `laplaceA`. Modifying the single line to be as follows should give numerical results without any `t` variables:

```
result_matrix = @(Input) subs(laplaceA,"t",Input);
```

---

To evaluate the trigonometric functions to numerical values

```
result_matrix = @(Input) vpa(subs(laplaceA,"t",Input));
```

---

### Full Script:

```
clc
clear
close all

% Parameters
syms s
r = 3.33;
l = 4.56*10^-3;
j = 4.96*10^-5;
b = 4.59*10^-5;
k = 0.0332;

% State Matrices
F = [-r/l -k/l 0; k/j -b/j 0; 0 1 0];
G = [1/l; 0; 0];


sI = s*eye(3,3);
aux_A = (adjoint(sI-F))/det(sI-F);
laplaceA = ilaplace(aux_A);

result_matrix = @(Input) vpa(subs(laplaceA,"t",Input));

%Assuming t = 0.01
result_matrix(0.01)
```

---

### Output Results:

[image: Output Results]

Comment: Any errors? It works on MATLAB version R2019b.

Comment: For numerical values where the trigonometric functions are evaluated down to numerical values use `result_matrix = @(Input) vpa(subs(laplaceA,"t",Input));`.

Comment: I'm using MATLAB version R2018b, vpa() solved it. Thank you so much!